# Using ActionBar in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

Can I still use ActionBar in AppCompatActivity? Are there any issues on using it from Android 6 to Android 4?

I know Toolbar is the new ActionBar, but if I still want to use ActionBar, is this is safe? The reason I don't want to use toolbar is because I'm already skinning the ActionBar.

Btw, I see a huge fragmentation in the API, almost confusing I would say.
There's Activity, AppCompatActivity and setActionBar, setSupportActionBar and ActionBar/Toolbar...

Comment: yes you can, but I suggest you to use 'toolbar', It is more Flexible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Toolbar will be a great option it can be highly customizable, which means you can add navigation buttons, logos, titles, subtitle, action menu items, or even your own custom views. If you still want ActionBar,You need to use getSupportActionBar() while using AppCompatActivity

[You can also check customizing option which toolbar provide to that of actionbar](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/)

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Answer:**  You need to use `getSupportActionBar()` if you are using `AppcompatActivity` irrespective of what version your app is running.

**Recommended:** Should you choose to use the new [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of `ActionBar`, because it's way too flexible.